# What is the word for "interaction with business for understanding requirements and present back"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to put in CV a succint term as responsibility for "interaction with business for understanding requirements and present back". Business representative ? business interaction (seems not good enough) ?

It would be in CV under the responsibility, telling my capacity of all steps in application/solution development : "management, [missing here for business interaction], design, development, integration, test, maintenance"

Comment: Gathering requirements from customers (although you  should  probably just put "stakeholders"). If it's back-and-forth work in "iterate" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're describing the role of a business analyst, which [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_analyst) defines as follows:

> A **business analyst (BA)** is someone who analyzes an organization or business domain (real or hypothetical) and documents its business or processes or systems, assessing the business model or its integration with technology

This role is well-known throughout all industries (though precise responsibilities may vary between companies).

If you need a word similar to 'design' and 'development', that would be 'business analysis', though in my experience that specific term is used less often.

Comment: It could be, but I have the feeling that Business Analyst is a role, while I am talking about a responsibility. As you know in any application, solution development, there should be this person who interact with business, understand and consolidate their needs (and even help them arrive at what they need in case they don't know), and then bridge between this requirements and development team, then present back to the business. In other words, a guy who is an interface between Business and Tech

Comment: Well, [business analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_analysis) comes close to that responsibility. It might be a bit broader than you intend, but it's not as broad and vague as "management" :)